# Unable to update a simple value inside a custom widget

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, widget

Hey guys I have made this code on flutter which fetches data from a different app through firebase and and I want to use showbottomsheet to make a widget I want the code to work such that when user taps on ADD button the bottomsheet  appears (this part is working) but I am unable to update the value when any different ADD button is pressed nor I can automatically pop the bottom sheet disapper if counter set to zero and counter reverts to add button have to press back button for the bottom sheet to fade out also I have not yet worked with state managment tools like provider so please explain if you use that in your code

see images for clarity
1:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrjJC.png

2:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNLrQ.png

3 (value should have incremented when item incremented):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT1Fx.png

4 (value did not update when new item added by adding into previous value but only the new value is shown also does change on incrementing or decrementing the counter):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fpI.png

the images may not be in order as I have to use links due to low reputation

code for menuscreen.dart:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dti_2/menu_design.dart';
import 'package:dti_2/progress_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'models/menu.dart';
import 'models/sellers.dart';
import 'package:dti_2/text_widget_header.dart';

class MenuScreens extends StatefulWidget {
  final Sellers? model;
  static const String id = "MenuScreens";
  const MenuScreens({super.key, this.model});

  @override
  State<MenuScreens> createState() => _MenuScreensState();
}

class _MenuScreensState extends State<MenuScreens> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0, 165, 30, 30),
          bottomOpacity: 0.0,
          elevation: 0.0,
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.black38,
              ))),
      body: Stack(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                  pinned: false,
                  delegate:
                      TextWidgetHeader(title: "${widget.model!.sellerName}")),
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("sellers")
                    .doc(widget.model!.sellerUID)
                    .collection('menus')
                    .orderBy("publishedDate", descending: true)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return !snapshot.hasData
                      ? SliverToBoxAdapter(
                          child: Center(
                            child: circularProgress(),
                          ),
                        )
                      : SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
                          crossAxisCount: 1,
                          staggeredTileBuilder: (c) =>
                              const StaggeredTile.fit(1),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            Menus rmodel = Menus.fromJson(
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()!
                                  as Map<String, dynamic>,
                            );
                            return MenuDesign(
                              model: rmodel,
                              context: context,
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

and code for menudesign where I am struggling to use this widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'models/menu.dart';
import 'assistant_method.dart';
// class Counter extends ChangeNotifier {

class MenuDesign extends StatefulWidget {
  Menus? model;
  BuildContext context;
  MenuDesign({
    super.key,
    required this.model,
    required this.context,
  });

  @override
  State<MenuDesign> createState() => _MenuDesignState();
  TextEditingController counterText = TextEditingController();

  bool isVisible = false;

  bool isVisiv() {
    // Add your implementation here to calculate the value of `isVisible`
    return isVisible;
  }
}

class _MenuDesignState extends State<MenuDesign> {
  bool isVisible = false;

  int? get itemCounter => null;

  bool isVisiv() {
    // Add your implementation here to calculate the value of `isVisible`
    return isVisible;
  }

  void closeBottomSheet() {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  int _count = 0;
  bool show = false;

  int total = 0;
  bool _showIncrementDecrementButtons = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.amber,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Column(children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                              size: const Size.fromRadius(58),
                              child: Image.network(widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                shadowColor: Colors.black),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              setState(() {
                                _showIncrementDecrementButtons =
                                    !_showIncrementDecrementButtons;
                                if (_showIncrementDecrementButtons) {
                                  showBottomSheet(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: ((builder) => bottomsheet()));

                                  _count = 1;
                                  total += int.parse(widget.model!.menuPrice!);

                                  // ignore: void_checks
                                  return;
                                } else {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                  total = 0;
                                  _count = 0;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            child: _showIncrementDecrementButtons
                                ? Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          total -= total;
                                          setState(() {
                                            if (_count > 1) {
                                              total -= int.parse(
                                                  widget.model!.menuPrice!);
                                              ;
                                              _count--;
                                            } else {
                                              total = 0;

                                              _showIncrementDecrementButtons =
                                                  false;
                                            }
                                          });
                                        },
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '$_count',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.green,
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                      ),
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          _count++;
                                          total += int.parse(
                                              widget.model!.menuPrice!);
                                          ;

                                          setState(() {
                                            total += total;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        icon: const Icon(
                                          Icons.add,
                                        ),
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                : const Text(
                                    'ADD',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                widget.model!.menuTitle!,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontFamily: "Proxima Nova",
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '₹ ${widget.model!.menuPrice!}',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 137, 52),
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  fontFamily: "Proxima Nova",
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              widget.model!.menuInfo!,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 122, 121, 121),
                                fontSize: 15,
                                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 0.0,
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    height: 3,
                    thickness: 2,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 201, 200, 200),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget bottomsheet() {
    return InkWell(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text(
                total.toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

some of the variables and functions shown here are never used and are present only as I was trying to fix the error so don't get confused if a function is never called or a var never used